# How to get Flow code working with server side node using babel-register?

Tags: node.js, babeljs, flowtype

I have some babel code mixed with flow, if I leave out the flow bits, the following `.babelrc` works just fine with a `require('babel-core/register')` wrapper on server-side node js.

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "env",
            {
                "targets": {
                    "node": "current"
                }
            }
        ]
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "syntax-class-properties"
    ]
}
```

However, if I import a file with `// @flow` and some flow code, and add `"transform-flow-strip-types"` to `.babelrc`, as follows:

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "env",
            {
                "targets": {
                    "node": "current"
                }
            }
        ]
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "syntax-class-properties",
        "transform-flow-strip-types"
    ]
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
[nodemon] starting `node --trace-warnings ./src/server/server.babel.js --inspect-workers`
/home/panoplos/Documents/Development/Node.js/testing/src/server/server.js:3
System.register(['fs', 'path', 'socketcluster', './utils/env'], function (_export, _context) {
^

ReferenceError: System is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/panoplos/Documents/Development/Node.js/testing/src/server/server.js:3:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at loader (/home/panoplos/Documents/Development/Node.js/testing/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/home/panoplos/Documents/Development/Node.js/testing/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/panoplos/Documents/Development/Node.js/testing/src/server/server.babel.js:2:1)
```

What am I doing wrong, here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this with the following `.babelrc` setup:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "flow",
        [
            "env",
            {
                "targets": {
                    "node": "current"
                }
            }
        ]
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "transform-class-properties"
    ]
}
```

Which required installing `babel-preset-flow` and `babel-plugin-transform-class-properties` instead of `babel-plugin-syntax-class-properties`.

Even after doing this, though I got the following error:

```
   [Error] /home/panoplos/Documents/Development/Node.js/testing/src/server/utils/errors.js:26
        static codes = {
                     ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at createScript (vm.js:53:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:95:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:543:28)
    at loader (/home/panoplos/Documents/Development/Node.js/testing/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/home/panoplos/Documents/Development/Node.js/testing/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

To get past this issue, had to delete `~/.babel.json`, which is apparently the `babel-register` cash file!

What a mess...but at least it works now.